# Yii Framework: Pagination in partial view

Tags: php, ajax, yii, pagination

Working under the Yii framework, I have a page that loads and lists different sections. This is, of course, done with `renderPartial` a few different views. One of the sections takes an array and displays a list of the items in it. What I need to do is have pagination only for this section, preferably using AJAX so I don't reload all the content upon page selection.

That's the first part of the problem. I've looked into using `CActiveDataProvider` with `CListView`, however, the problem there is that I'm displaying information from an array that's unrelated to the database. In other words, there's no conditions and so on to create the array, I just have a bunch of `$items` and that's about it. Any tips appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`CArrayDataProvider`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CArrayDataProvider) instance as the `dataProvider` for the `CListView`. It has inbuilt pagination support though you may have to explicitly set the pagination's `currentPage`.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to use the CArrayDataProvider with a regular array and not something related to the database as it is in my case?

Comment: Several things actually but I got too wrapped in the code. I'll clean it up and start over, then I'll update the question if I'm still struggling. Thanks!

Comment: Well, I tried from a clean start, using a simple $items array: $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider($items, array(
            'pagination' => array(
                'PageSize' => 10,
            ) 
        ));
Then simple list to display it: $this->widget('CLinkPager',array('pages'=>$dataProvider, "cssFile" => false)) and then I get the following error:
CActiveDataProvider and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "getPageCount".

Comment: Err, here's the correct code in the view using CListView instead of CLinkPage: $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        'itemView'=>'view',
        'template'=>"{items}\n{pager}",
      ));

Comment: Should it be `$dataProvider = new CArrayDataProvider( ...`? Also please add your code to your question instead of putting it in comments. It's much easier to format.

Comment: Aaah, Array vs Active, never noticed that were actually two different classes. Thank you very much and sorry for the code in the comments!

Answer (score 1):

You can use CLinkPager without CGridView, there is an example:

In controller:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria -> order = 'date';
$pages = new CPagination(Posts::model() -> count());
$pages -> pageSize = 50;
$pages -> applyLimit($criteria);
$posts= Posts::model() -> findAll($criteria);
$this -> controller -> render('list', array('posts' => $posts, 'pages' => $pages));
```

In view:

```
<?php $this->widget('CLinkPager',array('pages'=>$pages, "cssFile" => false)); ?>
<ul>
<?php foreach($posts as $x => $post): ?>
  <li><?php echo $post -> title ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php $this->widget('CLinkPager',array('pages'=>$pages, "cssFile" => false)); ?>
```

Comment: The problem here is that I don't have criteria. I just have an array of $items unrelated to the database so the applyLimit part cannot work for me.